# Не включается слайдер в opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: opencart

Делал сайт на opencart 2.3.0.2 , убрал слайдер и наверное (уже не помню) убрал его свойства в css так как редактировал шапку и теперь он не включается. Или причина в другом?

Answer (score 0):

**Включить слайдер на главной странице:**

Дизайн > Схемы > Главная > Редактирование темы(синяя кнопка справа)

По умолчанию этот слайдер называется **Слайдшоу** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в даной настройке слайдер будет присутствовать, значит он отключён для отображения. Проверить данную настройку так:

Дополнения - Модули - Слайдшоу>Home Page - Редактирование(синяя кнопка) - Статус (Должен быть **Вкючено**)

Если же и тут всё в порядке, то, скорее всего, модуль скрыт от отображения css-правилами. Тогда секите в DevTools вашего браузера айдишник/класс слайдера и ищите в style.css

З.С. Название модуля и цвета кнопок могут не совпадать, в зависимости от используемых расширений. Я описал случай для дефолтной админки.